# Call to a member function result() using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am having a strange issue with mysql and codeigniter. I am getting the following error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in
```

Controller:

```
class Event extends Client_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Event_Model', '', TRUE);
    }

    function pending()
    {
        $data['query'] = $this->Event_Model->get_events_list("pending");
        $this->load->view('event/pending', $data);
    }   

}
```

Model:

```
class Event_Model extends Client_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_events_list($event_status = '')
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_events WHERE event_status= ? ORDER BY event_id DESC", array($event_status));

        return $query->result();// Error is on this line
    }
}
```

Autoload:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Any help is appreciated. I have some doubts that my mysql might time-out?

Answer (score 3):

The error is likely due to the fact that the query (and resulting `result()` object) are empty. Ensure that the query actually returns at least one record before attempting to use the `result()` object:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
}
```

Comment: not an answer, but a tip.. you should avoid two things.. using `SELECT *` as its more resource intensive, and you should use active records when at all possible.. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: I did try this: Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in. I believe it is on driver or database level I am using * just for the code here ..

Comment: @animatora: You should verify your database connection and config information then.

Comment: It seems my mysql was corrupted, just updated it and now works fine. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 2):

Usually it's because your query is wrong. Remember that `result()` is boolean and if nothing comes back it is a fatal error since in the SQL server an error returned

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for taking the time to answer this question.

However, stackoverflow.com is an English-only site. Please edit your answer to remove the Spanish part.

Note: if you want, you can also participate on Spanish Stack Overflow https://es.stackoverflow.com/ - there, you would have to remove English paragraphs ;-)