# rows from db in header, which set to display in all page

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter I'm try to made header with code from DB, my controller code:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('main_model');
    $data['result'] = $this->main_model->get_tipsters();
    $this->load->view('template/header_view',$data);
}
```

And header_view:

```
<?php foreach($result->result() as $row): ?>
    <div id="tipster"><a href="<?=site_url();?>/bets/author/<?=$row->name;?>"><img src="<?=$row->photo;?>" /><br /><?=$row->name;?></a></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Header work's only It self view file, but not In others pages.
I Including header like this in controllers:

```
$this->load->view('template/header_view');
$this->load->view("/bets/index",$data);
$this->load->view('template/footer_view');
```

Getting this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered    
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: result
Filename: template/header_view.php
Line Number: 14

Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in /home/user/domains/test.com/public_html/application/views/template/header_view.php on line 14
```

Line 14 is foreach, I have copied early.

Comment: It's probably because of the way you're trying to access the "bets" folder `/bets/index` - You can try a full system path instead `/var/user/you/httpdocs/bets/index` or a relative one `../bets/index` depending on where you're executing from.

Comment: @Fred-ii- But /bets/index/ is view folder :) System knows where is it

Comment: Then try applying it to your `view('template/header_view')` etc. It's definitely a path issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- This is not view problem, updated first post

Comment: Did you Google the error? I found this related Q&A on Stack http://stackoverflow.com/q/9490598/ so it's most likely that your query failed.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I know that this error because result() not giving any results from db, and what I ask is possible to get result in header from db in all my site pages

Comment: See the answer below then.

Answer (score 0):

Since your header view file is always expecting `$result`, you'll need to provide it for **all** your controller methods:

```
$this->load->model('main_model');
$data['result'] = $this->main_model->get_tipsters();
$data['main'] = $this->main_model->get_main_data(); //example
$this->load->view('template/header_view',$data);
$this->load->view("bets/index",$data);
$this->load->view('template/footer_view');
```

This can become cumbersome, so consider creating a MY_Controller file that extends CI_Controller - [more about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16171046/data-available-for-all-views-in-codeigniter/16171508#16171508).

Comment: I put that code to my index, but still getting error

Comment: Does `$this->main_model->get_tipsters();` actually return any results?

Comment: Yes it is when i looking at site.com/index.php/main/ with this code in cotroller: `<?php 

class Main extends CI_Controller {

 public function index()
 {
  $this->load->model('main_model');
  $data['result'] = $this->main_model->get_tipsters();
  $this->load->view('template/header_view',$data);
 }
}
?>`

Comment: ... and if you put this code in another method inside the same Main class, it gives an error?

Comment: In main controller I inserted $data from db to my header_view, which I'm included to all pages, but It only works on main controller function url.. :S

Comment: So, `$this->main_model->get_tipsters();` only returns a result on the main index function? In that case there's a problem with your query which is beyond the scope of your original question...

Comment: Yes, it returns a result only on main index function. Possible to make it global?

Comment: That is question which I propose you ask in a new thread. In it, post the db query so we can see what's going on there.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function in your Common_model
 for fecthing result on your header file.

and directly get result from that function by calling it in a view file.

common_model.php

```
function your_function()
{
// code for fetching data for header
/// return your result here
}
```

call directly this function in a view file as

```
$rs = $this->Common_model->your_function();
```

Note: common_model is load by default .if disable then you need to load model in a view file.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to load `CI` object on view element file(header_view) and load and call model method with `CI` object

```
$CI = & get_instance()
$CI->load->model('main_model');
$result = $CI->main_model->get_tipsters();
<?php foreach($result->result() as $row): ?>
    <div id="tipster"><a href="<?=site_url();?>/bets/author/<?=$row->name;?>"><img src="<?=$row->photo;?>" /><br /><?=$row->name;?></a></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and remove code from controller